# How to put minus in front of specific texts stored in a list [R]

Tags: r, dataframe, text, merge

I have a list as shown below:

```
name <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
n <- c("1, 2, 3, 4, 5", "6, 7, 8", "9, 10", "11, 12, 13, 14", "15, 16, 17")
type <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

list <- list(name=name, n=n, type=type)

> list
$name
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"

$n
[1] "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"  "6, 7, 8"        "9, 10"          "11, 12, 13, 14" "15, 16, 17"    

$type
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

- The list has three variables, named `name`, `n` and `type`
- Each element are corresponded to each (i.e., `type` of `name=A` is `a`), thus, the number of vectors in each element is the same
- `n` stores a series of integers which are stored in string split by `comma (,)` (i.e., `n` of `name=A` is `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`)
- `n` may have different number of integers

On the other hand, I have another data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  name=c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","D","D","D","D","E","E","E"),
n=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17),
yn=c("Yes","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","Yes","Yes","No","Yes","Yes","Yes"))

> df
   name  n  yn
1     A  1 Yes
2     A  2 Yes
3     A  3  No
4     A  4  No
5     A  5 Yes
6     B  6  No
7     B  7 Yes
8     B  8 Yes
9     C  9 Yes
10    C 10 Yes
11    D 11  No
12    D 12 Yes
13    D 13 Yes
14    D 14  No
15    E 15 Yes
16    E 16 Yes
17    E 17 Yes
```

- Data frame has a list of `n` which are corresponded with `name` and `n` in the list
- In addition, this data frame has another attribute `yn` which defines whether the node is `yes` or `no`

I want to put `minus (-)` in front of the integer stored in the `list` if the corresponded `yn` in data frame is `No` as shown below:

[image]

Is anyone who can implement this operation?
It seems a bit weird manipulation but I need to keep the structure of the list.

Your suggestions are highly appreciated!!

Comment: "but I need to keep the structure of the list" No, you don't. You can bring it into a more useful format (e.g., split the number strings) and recreate the original format in the end.

Comment: Yes, I think it may be better to convert the original format into more convenient one first, then get back to the original format. I am looking for such a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring the data in dataframe, mulitply the values based on `yn` and get the data in list format again.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

bind_rows(list) %>%
  separate_rows(n, sep = ',\\s*', convert = TRUE) %>%
  left_join(df, by = c('name', 'n')) %>%
  mutate(n = n * ifelse(yn == 'No', -1, 1)) %>%
  group_by(name, type) %>%
  summarise(n = toString(n), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  as.list()

#$name
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"

#$type
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"

#$n
#[1] "1, 2, -3, -4, 5"  "-6, 7, 8"         "9, 10"            "-11, 12, 13, -14" "15, 16, 17"
```

Answer (score 1):

With base R:

```r
sf <- function(y, x){
    z <- df$yn[which(df$n %in% as.numeric(y) & df$name == list$name[x])]
    y[which(z == "No")] <- paste0("-",y[which(z == "No")])
    return(y)
}

> list$n <- sapply(seq_along(list$n), function(x) {gsub(" -", "-", paste(sapply(strsplit(list$n[x], split = ", "), sf, x), collapse = ", "))})
> list
$name
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"

$n
[1] "1, 2,-3,-4, 5"   "-6, 7, 8"        "9, 10"           "-11, 12, 13,-14" "15, 16, 17"     

$type
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below

```
list2DF(lst) %>%
  separate_rows(n, convert = TRUE) %>%
  left_join(df) %>%
  mutate(n = n * (2 * (yn == "Yes") - 1)) %>%
  group_by(name, type) %>%
  summarise(n = toString(n)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  as.list()
```

which gives

```
$name
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"

$type
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"

$n
[1] "1, 2, -3, -4, 5"  "-6, 7, 8"         "9, 10"            "-11, 12, 13, -14"
[5] "15, 16, 17"
```

Comment: @akrn As far as I know, one advantage is dealing with nonequal-length lists, e.g., `lst <- list(a = 1:2,b = 2:6)`. It is fine if we run `list2DF(lst)`, but `data.frame(lst)` will give an error. Maybe there are some other merits, but my knowledge on it is limited.

Comment: Thanks, that was the example I was looking for